# Visual Studio won't open vb solution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to open a VB solution on Visual Studio 2013 it won't open. Instead I can open the vb file but I can't run the program. Whenever I run it, it gives me this error message.

C:\Users\George\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\RealCalc\RealCalc\RealCalc.vbproj : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.  C:\Users\George\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\RealCalc\RealCalc\RealCalc.vbproj.user

Please help

Comment: Sounds like the project file got corrupted.  You might be able to fix it in notepad if it's not too bad.

Comment: See if there is a RealCalc.sln file and try to open that,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either your vbproj or vbproj.user file is corrupted. The first few lines of these files should look like this (note the root XML node):
vbproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
```

vbproj.user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
  ...
```

I'd suggest trying to fix it by hand using a good text editor. You can also try deleting the vbproj.user file altogether and letting VS regenerate it.

Comment: I think that The vbproj.user file got corrupted because none of the things that you said that were in it  were in it. I just said null over and over. I will see if this works